# Help with $\int \frac{1}{2x^2-4x+3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Regarding $\int \frac{1}{2x^2-4x+3}dx$:

I have checked the answer, and it is different than what I calculated, and I can't find my mistake:

$$\int \frac{1}{2x^2-4x+3}dx=\int \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt2 x-\sqrt2)^2}dx=\int \frac{1}{1+t^2}dx=\arctan(t)+C=$$

$$=\arctan(\sqrt2 x-\sqrt2)+C$$

And the solution is $\int \frac{1}{2x^2-4x+3}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan(\sqrt2 x-\sqrt2)+C$

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to replace the $dx$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}dt$.

Comment: Oh right!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the chain rule.  The strategy would be to complete the square, as you have done.  When you differentiate you get a factor of  $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Cool, thank you!!